# Is any possible to edit yii:powered() in Yii framework?

Tags: php, yii

I am using Yii framework for developing web application.i need to change my application name instead of "yii framework" in footer .For that i not able to find the function yii:powered().i need to edit the yii:powered() function.can anyone help me? Advance in thanks.

Comment: Why not simply delete the function and write you own company name in footer?

Comment: @Bahdeng : I know  it is simple only .But i want to know how to edit Yii:powered() function.i not able to find this function , where it is placed in Yii framework.

Comment: The function is in YiiBase.php its inside Yii->framework folder

Comment: ya got it, Thank you.One more Doubt.I am using netbeans . Through netbeans can i edit this yii:powered() function.

Comment: Don't edit it. When there will be a update for the framework your changes wille be overwritten. Better is it to create a new function.

Comment: ya its correct Michiel. My doubt, is there any possible to edit or see this function in netbeans IDE.Because i am using netbeans to develop the web.if possible means please tel...?

Answer (score 1):

How about extending the functionalities using your own Class ?

```
<?php
class CustomYii extends Yii
{
    public static function powered()
    {
        echo "Powered by My Company";
    }
}
```

Try to put the code inside `protected/components/CustomYii.php` and use it as follow

```
CustomYii::powered();
```

Comment: Hi Prabowo Murti - where to put the file CustomYii.php in yii2 as there is no folder as `protected/components` in Yii2. Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know. I misunderstand the question. I thought that the OP is using Yii version 1.x.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i found this file on themes/classic/views/layouts/main.php you can change here yii:powered() information.

Answer (score 1):

In Yii2 you can hard code powered() method using following path

{yourproject}\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php

`public static function powered()
    {
        return 'Powered by <a href="#" rel="external">ABC Company</a>';
    }`

Comment: you never change anything in the core files, you should always extend to override it

Comment: yes that might be a correct solution for do that. Those days i was a new to Yii 2 Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Because the string is hard coded in framework/YiiBase.php, 
I don't think It's good approach to override the function.

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.15/framework/YiiBase.php#L548

```
public static function powered()
    {
        return Yii::t('yii','Powered by {yii}.', array('{yii}'=>'<a href="http://www.yiiframework.com/" rel="external">Yii Framework</a>'));
    }
```

Why don't you replace `Yii::powered()` with `Yii::app()->name`, So that you can define the string in config file ?